# How to speed up asp.net web forms application with asp.net 3.5 url routing?

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I started using url routing for my web application. It's a dynamic website and it has more than 50k pages. It looks like now it works slower. Can you suggest how to optimize it, to improve it and make it more efficient?

Comment: Depends how you are creating your routes. Maybe you have too many rules, maybe your regex is too loose, could be a number of things. Show some of your routes, you'll get more answers.

Comment: Here is the one of the routes that I have in my Global.asax file. I have 15 more with similar but simpler logic
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route("Text/Text/{parameter}/{parameter2}/{parameter3}/{parameter4}/{parameter5}",
                                  new CsRouteHandler("~/pagename.aspx")));

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by enabling tracing on your website:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we%28VS.71%29.aspx

This should at least help you identify where the bottlenecks are really occurring (and provide you with some real timings rather than just ""). You can then use that info to start digging into your code to locate the exact bottleneck.

Comment: Thats good idea, but I have a different concern. My application was working fast enough before I implemented url routing. The tracing will not help with this

Comment: How do you know that tracing won't help if you haven't tried it? If you add tracing, you can add your own trace statements in prior to, during and after, the routing starts and finishes and view the timings in between. That will at least give you concrete timings that you can work with when you create your test plans to test different methods.